# Getting server response in angular interceptor responseError

Tags: javascript, angularjs, interceptor

I just built an interceptor Service in angularJS to catch all errors from API calls to handle general errors like so:

```
$provide.factory('myHttpInterceptor', function($q, dependency1, dependency2) {
  return {
   'responseError': function(rejection) {
      alert("Something went wrong");
      return $q.reject(rejection);
    }
  };
});
```

Works prefectly and my server sends back this on error with a status of `409`

```
{
message: "Email is already being used"
success: false
token: ""
}
```

How can access this response from the `responseError` interceptor?

Comment: What is available on the rejection object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it can be done like this

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q',  function($q) {
        return {
            'request': function (config) {
               //request codes
                return config;
            },
            'responseError': function(response) {

                console.log(response);
                if(response.statusText){

                    alert(response.statusText)
                }else{
                    alert("Server down")
                }
                if(response.status === 401 || response.status === 409) {
                    //response code
                }
                return $q.reject(response);
            }

        };
}]);
```

})

Answer (score 1):

```
$provide.factory('myHttpInterceptor', function($q, dependency1, dependency2) {
  return {
   'responseError': function(rejection) {
      if(rejection.status === 409) {
          //get set the error message from rejection.message/rejection.data.message and do what you want
      }
      alert("Something went wrong");
      return $q.reject(rejection);
    }
  };
});
```